# Applying a dynamic css property on a prop if value is null in React

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, jsx

Picking up another developers project in which he uses inline React extensively in this WordPress project. Really hard to follow and get to grip with. I've simplified the code block as much as possible.

```
const RangeViewer = ({ range, products, setActiveModelId, setModalIsOpen, bodyStyle }) => (
  <section className="productViewer" data-bodystyle={bodyStyle} data-range-name={range.name}>
    <div className="productViewer-list pb-2">
      .....
      .....
<a style={{!product.productAcfFields.playerUrl ? minWidth: '100%' : ''}} >example</a>
      .....
      .....
    </div>
   </section>
```

```
</div>
```

If the variable given in the ternary is null, empty or not specified I want style="min-width: 100%;" applied to the element otherwise nothing.

Comment: sorry wdym by not specified here ? undefined 

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition in style like this:

```
style={{minWidth: !product.productAcfFields.playerUrl ? '100%' : 'auto'}}
```

Comment: Then Check as Answer.